# Color issues with the ieeecolor document class and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, ieeecolor

I have been encountering a very strange behaviour with the `ieeecolor.cls` document class! Compiling a latex document using this class with the `tikz` package triggers some color warnings: `Warning Incompatible color definition`, but the pdf generated seems to be as expected (i.e. see MWE below).

However, very odd things happen when the following section is added to the tex file:

```
%%%% Inverse PDF page and text color
\definecolor{pagcol}{rgb}{0.1255,0.1255,0.1255}
\definecolor{txtcol}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\pagecolor{pagcol}
\color{txtcol}
```

In this case, the behaviour of latex is rather unexpected and the colors are not as they should anymore. This seems to come from a clash between the new `ieeecolor` class and some packages like `tikz`.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Has anyone find a fix for this?

The `ieeecolor` class can be found on the [IEEE Author Centre Website](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/), it requires the files `ieeecolor.cls` and 'generic.sty'.

---

Minimum working example with page and text color code commented:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
%       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
%\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out
                                                        % if you need a4paper
%\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}    % Use this line for a4
                                                        % paper
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}          % %% NEW ieeecolor class %%
% \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                          % This command is only
                                                        % needed if you want to
                                                        % use the \thanks command
% \overrideIEEEmargins
% See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
% on the last page of the document

% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
\usepackage{generic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

%%%%% Inverse PDF page and text color
%\definecolor{pagcol}{rgb}{0.1255,0.1255,0.1255}
%\definecolor{txtcol}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
%\pagecolor{pagcol}
%\color{txtcol}


\title{My Dummy Article}

\author{Julius~Caesar~\IEEEmembership{Fellow~Member,~IEEE}
\thanks{J.~Caesar is with the Senate House, Rome}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Key word 1, Key word 2.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Dummy Section 1}

\lipsum

\section{Dummy Section 2}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A Dummy Square figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

---

**generic.sty**

```
\def\logoname{LOGO-generic-web}
\definecolor{subsectioncolor}{rgb}{0,0.541,0.855}
\setlength{\firstpagerule}{39pc}
\setlength{\logowidth}{4pc}
\def\journalname{Generic Colorized Journal}
```

Answer (score 6):

`ieeecolor.sty` is a bit of a pain in the back. BTW, does anybody know who can be contacted to post patches?

There are two technical problems here, and one philosophical thing.

The philosophical thing is: is it worth caring? When they accept your paper, they will re-format it with something that's not LaTeX at all, and they want separate figures anyway, which are better build with `standalone`. But if you want your file working for internal use or submission to some archive, then yes, maybe it's worth it to care.

The technical problems are two:

1. the first one is quite big: [color will leak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583092/pop-empty-color-page-stack-0-with-ieeecolor-document-class). The linked answer provides a nice answer for it.
2. The package loads `color`, not `xcolor` (in 2021!), which is why you have all the problems with Ti*k*Z, which requires `xcolor`.

Possible solutions.

1. patch `ieeecolor.cls`

```
--- ieeecolor.cls.orig  2021-06-04 11:51:15.355826034 +0200
+++ ieeecolor.cls   2021-06-04 12:11:40.354385057 +0200
@@ -667,12 +667,13 @@
 %
 %
 %
-%
+
 \ProvidesClass{IEEEtran}[2002/11/18 revision V1.6b by Michael Shell]
 \typeout{-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.}
 \typeout{-- The source comments contain changelog notes.}
 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
-\RequirePackage{color}
+% \RequirePackage{color}
+\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%
 \DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
@@ -2255,16 +2256,16 @@
 \else
 \@IEEEfigurecaptionsepspace% V1.6 was a hard coded 5pt
 % 3/2001 use footnotesize, not small; use two nonbreaking spaces, not one
-\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\footnotesize #1.\color{black}\normalcolor~~\sf\boldmath #2}%
+\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\footnotesize #1.\color{black}\normalcolor~~\sf\boldmath #2}}%
 \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize%
 % if caption is longer than a line, let it wrap around
-\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\footnotesize #1.\color{black}\normalcolor~~ }%
+\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\footnotesize #1.\color{black}\normalcolor~~ }}%
 \parbox[t]{\hsize}{\footnotesize \noindent\unhbox\@tempboxa\sf\boldmath #2}%
 % if caption is shorter than a line,
 % allow user to control short figure caption justification (left or center)
 \else%
-\ifcenterfigcaptions \hbox to\hsize{\footnotesize\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
-\else \hbox to\hsize{\footnotesize\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
+\ifcenterfigcaptions \hbox to\hsize{{\footnotesize\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}}%
+\else \hbox to\hsize{{\footnotesize\box\@tempboxa\hfil}}%
 \fi\fi\fi\color{black}}
```

This should fix both problems, I think.

2. If you do not want to touch the original class, let's try to trick `ieeecolor`  by loading `xcolor` before the class; fix the other problem [with Phelype Oleinik fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583096/38080): just change your invocation of `\documentclass` with (tested using the `ieeecolor.cls` downloaded this morning!):

```latex
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}          % %% NEW ieeecolor class %%
% \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                          % This command is only
                                                        % needed if you want to
% Fix ieeecolor's \caption
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{color@begingroup}%
  {\let\color@begingroup\relax
   \let\color@endgroup\relax}{}%
\def\fix@ieeecolor@hbox#1{%
  \hbox{\color@begingroup#1\color@endgroup}}
\patchcmd\@makecaption{\hbox}{\fix@ieeecolor@hbox}{}{\FAILED}
\patchcmd\@makecaption{\hbox}{\fix@ieeecolor@hbox}{}{\FAILED}
```

Both seem to work for me, but I had no time to check deeply.

Comment: two years later, they still use color (not xcolor). and the latest update to the class-file was 5 years ago