# "pop empty color page stack 0" with ieeecolor document class

Tags: color, warnings, ieeecolor

I am still using `ieeecolor.cls` - get it from https://www.embs.org/tmi/authors-instructions/, namely, https://www.embs.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/TMI-Template-LaTeX-2020.zip

With this very short MWE,

```
\documentclass[print]{ieeecolor}
\usepackage{tmi}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{X}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get a

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: pop empty color page stack 0
```

presumably due to the colored caption. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug in `ieeecolor.cls`.  It misuses `\color` with `\hbox` and the scope of the colour `\special` “leaks”.  The problem narrows down to this (see how `world` is red too):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\setbox0\hbox{\color{red}hello}
\box0 world
\end{document}
```

The `\color` is inserted in the `\hbox`, and that box is later used, but since no grouping was performed when `\color` was used (it acts at the time the box is *used*, rather than when it's set), there was a missing “end color” instruction. If you use just `\hbox{\color{red}hello}` (that is, no `\setbox`...`\box`), then the implicit end group from the `\hbox` ends the colour, because the box is being *used*.

Here's a patch for that.  It inserts `\color@begingroup` and `\color@endgroup` around the contents of the box, so that the `\color` properly ends:

```latex
\documentclass[print]{ieeecolor}
\usepackage{tmi}

% Fix ieeecolor's \caption
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{color@begingroup}%
  {\let\color@begingroup\relax
   \let\color@endgroup\relax}{}%
\def\fix@ieeecolor@hbox#1{%
  \hbox{\color@begingroup#1\color@endgroup}}
\patchcmd\@makecaption{\hbox}{\fix@ieeecolor@hbox}{}{\FAILED}
\patchcmd\@makecaption{\hbox}{\fix@ieeecolor@hbox}{}{\FAILED}
%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{X}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It fixed my recurring issues of different parts of body text getting colored seemingly randomly