# When writing with IEEE templates, the color of the body suddenly turns blue

Tags: color, ieeetran

[image]

when I add or delete some body text before, some body text will change color. I do not know why. I did not change any setting of the ieeecolor.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Please add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), so the others can help you. MWE is the minimal code that produces the problem you have encountered.

Comment: First, did you mess with the caption, or is Fig. always that color?

Comment: Thank you@Imran @John very much for answering my question. The blue text was previously displayed as black normally. If I delete a paragraph of text in the left-hand sub-column, this blue text turns back to black.

Comment: This also looks like the color hyperref uses for links.  Maybe you started a link and didn't close it.

Comment: If you know what text to delete, it would really help to see it.

Comment: Thanks again for answering my question, I've just been using latex for three days and all I did was add body text to the template provided by IEEE, I didn't use the link command.@JohnKormylo

Comment: Delete any more than tow lines before will work. Sometimes when I write a new paragraph, the later sections will turn blue strangely.@JohnKormylo

Comment: The color is the same as the "fig" label and the subsection title such as 'A. Overview of disentanglement'. @JohnKormylo

Comment: Colors can leak if you use wrong code. But to find the problem you really need to give more information. Which ieee template are you using? Can you show your code?

Comment: Could you please try my second solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599917/38080 ? @UlrikeFischer that seems the color leak discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583096/38080

Comment: @JohnKormylo if the documentclass is `ieeecolor`, probably is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599917/38080

Comment: IEEE has new templates which can be downloaded from https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/.  IIRC, they do not come with documentation.  They do have a new \Figure command and lots of logo images.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.@UlrikeFischer，@Rmano，@JohnKormylo. I didn't reply in time before because my time zone may be different from you. The template I used is 'ieeecolor' which downloaded from [link](ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org). I didn't change any parameters, just wrote my own body and added my own images according to the example of adding images given by the template.

Comment: I find that the problem is solved or occurs when I add or remove text from the previous page thus changing the position of the color-changing part of the text in the pdf document, and sometimes the problem occurs with random sections on later pages. All I did was add or subtract text in the paragraph, I did not modify the command.

Comment: I have checked the solution given by @Rmano. First of all, thank you very much for your patience. I have not used the \hbox command and it is not used in the template. So I think I am in a different situation than in the link. I'm still a latex newbie, so I'm afraid to and haven't modified the command in the template.

Comment: Are you sure you checked the patch? You do not need to use box yourself, it's used by the template inside the caption command, and given your example it seems that the color is leaked from there. If you can copy your project to a new one showing the problem I can have a look.

Comment: @Rmano  thank you again. I used the patch "Fix ieeecolor's \caption" you provided. And It worked. For I am just a Newbie of latex and English is not my mothe language, I do not know which part of code I should copy to show. Though the problems look different, this really help me.  Thank you : )